# How do I change the height of the tab indicator in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change the height/thickness of the tab indicator in material ui

*From this*

[image]

*To this*

[image]

Comment: What version of material-ui do you use? 0.xx or 1.xx?

Comment: I am currently using v1.0.0-beta.24

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use `sx` in MUI v5, then:

```
<Tabs
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    sx: {
      bgcolor: "orange"
      height: "10px"
    }
  }}
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={value}
>
  <Tab label="Item One" />
  <Tab label="Item Two" />
  <Tab label="Item Three" />
</Tabs>
```

---

You can change it with `TabIndicatorProps`.

```
<Tabs
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: {
      height:"10px",
    }
  }}
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={value}
>
  <Tab label="Item One" />
  <Tab label="Item Two" />
  <Tab label="Item Three" />
</Tabs>
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `indicatorClassName` property was removed in the v1.0.0-beta.37 release. The `classes` property is now the standard way to customize the internal styles of components in v1.

For details about this change, see [the release notes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.37)

```js
// Define custom styles
const styles = theme => ({
  bigIndicator: {
    height: 5
  }
})


<Tabs
  /* use the `classes` property to inject styles for the indicator class */
  classes={{ indicator: classes.bigIndicator }}
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={value}
>
  <Tab label="Item One" />
  <Tab label="Item Two" />
  <Tab label="Item Three" />
</Tabs>
```

Here is a complete [working example on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjj5j6284?hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fdemo.js)

Answer (score 2):

**Standard way:** you can change it in the `theme.js` file for entire the project:

```
components: {
   MuiTabs: {
      styleOverrides: {
         indicator: {
            height: 6
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Or to change only one specific tabs you can use `TabIndicatorProps`:

```
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {height: 6}}} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
   <Tab label='Item One' />
   <Tab label='Item Two' />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a class name to the TabIndicator via the [Tabs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/tabs/) component by using its `indicatorClassName` prop:

```js
  const styles = theme => ({
    bigIndicator: {
      height: 5,
    },
  });
```

```js
    <Tabs indicatorClassName={classes.bigIndicator} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <Tab label="Item One" />
      <Tab label="Item Two" />
      <Tab label="Item Three" href="#basic-tabs" />
    </Tabs>
```

Here is a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j29kmjwlq)

Comment: This will not work as indicatorClassName is not accepted props, check: https://material-ui.com/api/tabs

Comment: To be fair, this answer was offered in 2017 for the `v1.0.0-beta.24` release, but yeah, it won't work today.

Answer (score -1):

You can change it with `indicatorHeight`.

```js
<Tabs indicatorHeight={4}>
    <Tab label="Item One" />
    <Tab label="Item Two" />
    <Tab label="Item Three" />
</Tabs>
```

This is the simplest way to change the height of the tab indicator in 2021.

Comment: Are you sure? Tabs hasn't such prop