# Change the thickness of Tabs' indicator in MUI

Tags: reactjs, frontend, material-ui

So basically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927414/how-do-i-change-the-height-of-the-tab-indicator-in-material-ui) is what I want to do.

`indicatorClassName` doesn't work for me and the indicator from [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j29kmjwlq) doesn't change at all. I looked through the component's [implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/Tabs.js) , and found `indicatorStyle`, but it didn't help neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an updated [example on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjj5j6284?module=%2Fdemo.js) that works with the latest version of material ui.

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Connect your component with custom styles using [withStyles](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#api)
2. Write your own style for indicator (or any other name of your choice)
3. Use it as below :

> ```
>           <Tabs
>             ...
>             classes={{indicator:classes.indicator}}
>           >
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) in **MUI v5**:

```
<Tabs
  {...}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    sx: {
      height: 5,
    },
  }}
>
```

Or if you want to set it in `createTheme()`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTabs: {
      styleOverrides: {
        indicator: {
          height: 3,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]